# Encoding method of Logistic Regression in Scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to use Logistic Regression to do some predicting task with Scikit-learn tool.

Hers are two example features of my task:

Feature 1(man, woman, unknow)   **---categorical variable**

Feature 2(number of clicking)   **---continuous variable**

I am not sure how to encode feature when I input data into Logistic Regression.

Should I use **1, 2 and 3** to represent categorical variable **man, woman and unknow**,  or use **(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)** to represent them when I use Scikit-learn's Logistic Regression? And how about the  continuous variable?

Comment: For categorical variables, always use one-hot encoding if it doesnt represent any underlying order as in your case. For continuos variable, they are already in numbers, so no need to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature 2 you should leave it as you have it.

Feature 1 is a little bit more tricky. When working with missing data, you either can drop the entire rows or try to impute values to the feature. I recommend you to read [Imputing missing values before building an estimator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/missing_values.html) from the Scikit-Learn documentation. This will show you an example of imputing data and testing that your prediction is improving. If you impute data do try adding a dummy variable for the row that has imputed data, I have successfully applied this specification in the past.